# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmltodict'

Tags: python-3.x, xmltodict, xml-to-json

I have installed xmltodict successfully using the below command

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --user xmltodict
```

But when I am executing a python script which contains import xmltodict I am getting the below error

```
import xmltodict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmltodict'
```

Can some please help me to fix this?

Comment: just `pip install xmltodict`. what command do you use for running python script?

Comment: python <scriptfile.py> is the one I used.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in pip 18.1. try to upgrade the pip first, uninstall and reinstall the xmltodict module.